# How to find the owner of a property?

Tags: python, class, oop, super

I have a simple class called A

```
class A(object):
    pass
```

I made an instance of class A in the variable "a"

```
a = A()
```

Then I created a property of a called "b", which is another instance of class A

```
a.b = A()
```

If I lose my reference to "a" like so

```
c = a.b
```

Is there a way to call some sort of function/method on c to return "a"

```
someFunction(c) == a or c.someMethod() == a
```

I thought I would have to use the super() function but I don't know.

**My Method**

I thought about it some more and this is how I decided to go about doing it

```
class notObject(object):
    pass

class A(notObject):
    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        if isinstance(value,A) and name!="parent":
            value.parent = self
        super(notObject,self).__setattr__(name, value)

a = A()
a.b = A()
c = a.b

c.parent==a
```

Now if someone could cleanup this code a little that would be appreciated. I didn't want to create a placeholder class "notObject" but if A inherited from object than I couldn't set attributes to its super.

Comment: Are you sure you made `b` a property, and not just an attribute?

Comment: I'm sure you can achieve this through reflection (`inspect` etc), but I can't imagine any situation in which this would be a *good* idea in production code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't in general, because there might not be one, or there might be more than one.  For instance, what if you did this:

```
a = A()
a.b = A()
c = a.b
del a.b
```

By deleting the attribute `a.b`, you remove the link between `a` and the the object formerly known as `a.b`.  The object is still there, but it no longer has any relationship with `a`.

Likewise, you could do this:

```
a1 = A()
a2 = A()
c = A()
a1.b = c
a2.b = c
```

Now what is the "owner" of `c`?  The same object is the value of an attribute of `a1` and of `a2`.  There's no way to choose between them.

There is no built-in notion of "ownership" in Python, because Python's built-in structures don't enforce any requirement that object be "owned by" or "referrable to via" exactly one object.  Any object can be referred to by any number of other objects.  If you want an object to have a notion of its "owner", you need to define that notion yourself and built it into the object (e.g., by giving it an "owner" property that you update yourself when you decide the ownership has changed).

Answer (score 1):

I know of 3 ways to handle this. In order of how much I would recommend them, they are:

1. Don't do it. If you need `a`, keep track of `a` instead of just its `b` attribute.
2. Give `a.b` an attribute that refers to `a`. Something like `a.b.owner = a`, though you'd want to do this in a way that doesn't make so much of a mess of objects sometimes having attributes and sometimes not.
3. Search `gc.get_referrers(c)` for an `A` instance whose `b` attribute is `c`. This is error-prone, since some other `A` instance might also have the same attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you lose your reference to an object, there is no way to get it back other than ... another reference. (Not that I know of anyway). If you need a reference to something... KEEP IT

You asked how to find the owner of a property.... but there is no single "owner"... per se... There is only the reference to that object. And there could be multiple references to any given object. Take the following example:

```
class A(object):
    pass

# Create an instance of A
a = A()

# Create a string object
myString = 'Test string'

# Assign the string to a.stringVal
a.stringVal = myString

# Create another instance of A
a2 = A()

# Assign the same string to a2.stringVal
a2.stringVal = myString
```

In this example... Who "Owns" myString?? Is it a or a2? The answer is that each of those objects only have a reference to the same object. And references are a one way street. You can follow a reference, but you can't go back the other way. In other words... If you only know myString, you can't get to a or a2. And there is no way that I know of to figure out what objects have a reference to a given object unless you can somehow scan every variable that you know of and test to see if a given property is the object you are checking.

Short answer. Don't lose references. If they are important... keep them. If an object needs another object, you should structure your classes so that dependencies are injected on object creation and that object keeps track of it's own dependencies. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection to learn more about this design pattern.